# If statement not exiting from For loop

Tags: if-statement, vbscript, exit

I am trying to use this code to exit a loop if an input angle is 90. The code does not do this but the frustrating part is that while I don't have anything exactly the same in the rest of my code I have used the same format `If` statement successfully. I have also successfully used `Exit For`.

Here is the code I am referring to.

```
If Not (Angle = 90) Then
  Exit For
End If
```

***I found my mistake but here is the code in case anyone runs into a similar mistake. I forgot that I had changed my angle from degrees to radians is all.

*Edit to show where *Angle* comes from:

```
oriInput = Split(Me.oriInputList.Value, ",")

ReDim toworis(NofLayers - 1)
For p = 0 To NofLayers - 1
toworis(p) = oriInput(p)
Next
```

This is where I went wrong. I changed the angle from radians to degrees so the angle was not 90 by the time it reached the `If` statement

```
For k = 0 To NofLayers - 1 Step 1

    toworis(k) = toworis(k) * pi / 180

Next

For j = 0 To NofLayers - 1 Step 1


    Angle = toworis(j)




For i = -cntr * 2 + cntrshift To cntr * 2 + cntrshift Step 1
  If Not (Angle = 90) Then
    Exit For
  End If

  '1
  x11 = 0
  x21 = pL
  y11 = i * yshift
  y21 = i * yshift + Tan(Angle) * pL

  '2
  x12 = 0
  x22 = 0
  y12 = i * yshift
  y22 = i * yshift - tW / Cos(Angle)

  '3
  x13 = 0
  x23 = pL
  y13 = i * yshift - tW / Cos(Angle)
  y23 = i * yshift - tW / Cos(Angle) + Tan(Angle) * pL

  '4
  x14 = pL
  x24 = pL
  y14 = i * yshift + Tan(Angle) * pL
  y24 = i * yshift - tW / Cos(Angle) + Tan(Angle) * pL

  Set line2D3 = factory2D1.CreateLine(x11, y11, x21, y21)
  Set line2D4 = factory2D1.CreateLine(x12, y12, x22, y22)
  Set line2D5 = factory2D1.CreateLine(x13, y13, x23, y23)
  Set line2D6 = factory2D1.CreateLine(x14, y14, x24, y24)
Next
```

If the angle is 90 this should create the layer

```
For l = cntrshift To cntr3 Step 1
  If (Angle <> 90) Then
    Exit For
  End If

  '1
  x11 = l * tW * (sT + 1) + shift * tW
  x21 = x11
  y11 = pW
  y21 = 0

  '2
  x12 = x11
  x22 = x11 + tW
  y12 = 0
  y22 = 0

  '3
  x13 = x11 + tW
  x23 = x13
  y13 = 0
  y23 = pW

  '4
  x14 = x11 + tW
  x24 = x11
  y14 = pW
  y24 = pW

  Set line2D3 = factory2D1.CreateLine(x11, y11, x21, y21)
  Set line2D4 = factory2D1.CreateLine(x12, y12, x22, y22)
  Set line2D5 = factory2D1.CreateLine(x13, y13, x23, y23)
  Set line2D6 = factory2D1.CreateLine(x14, y14, x24, y24)
Next
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you set the value for variable `angle` that you test in your `if` statement. Is it always unset and therefore never trips the `if`?

Comment: Like JNevill said, you never change `Angle` inside your loop, so if the value is 90 from the outset the condition will never be triggered. If the value is not 90 the loop will always exit immediately. This includes float/double values that aren't *exactly* 90.00000000000000000... If `Angle` is a float or double value use the `Round` function to avoid this issue.

Comment: Sorry I should've included more but I didn't want to crowd the post. The angle is set outside of these loops by user input. My purpose is to select a loop based on if angle=90 or not (I know I could use select case. I tried after posting this but with exactly the same results). @AnsgarWiechers

Comment: Set by user input *how*? With *what* results? You still haven't explained what does not work the way you expected. Please make your code a [mcve] so that we can actually reproduce your problem.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I found my mistake while I was going to add in the code to show you where I was getting the angle from. I'm sorry for the incomplete question. I see the logic of including everything even though I thought I was sure how the angle was coming in. Thanks for your help